# Time during which steam prevents the sale of items unless I buy more games

Tags: steam

I bought some games in Steam about 1 or 2 years ago. Recently I got some cards and items and I wanted to sell them. After all this time when pressing the sell button on such items. A message (translated) comes up saying:

> A game is required to be bought, otherwise you will not be able to sell items anymore.

Something like that, At the time I was told by Steam that I had and estimated time of three moths left to do that. If that is the case how much time do I have until I'm required to buy something again to be able to sell items?

Comment: Spanish? Oh Argentina I see.
_Pon tu pregunta aquí en los comentarios en español y yo me encargaré de editar tu pregunta original, o alguien más si se me adelantan_

Comment: Ah, perfecto.

La cosa es así, en Steam, yo compre juegos hace 1 año 2, y los items-cromos y cosas así que gane quería venderlas, cuando voy a venderlas, luego de mucho tiempo, en el botón vender sale un cartel que dice: Se necesita comprar un juego, o se perderá el privilegio de vender sus objetos*  Algo así, y tenia un tiempo estimado de 3 meses para hacer eso.

si es así ¿cuanto tiempo tengo para que vuelva a pasar eso?

Comment: _Listo, ahora necesita ser aprovada, ya sea por ti, o por mods_

Comment: Can you please write in English so other readers can also benefit from your conversation?

Comment: @Philipp OP's original question was a badly translated question from Spanish, I asked him to write the question in Spanish so I would edit the original question with a better translation. That's what the conversation is about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your account must have purchased a game between thirty days and one year ago. This means that if you don't purchase anything for a whole year, you will lose access to the marketplace.

From the Steam FAQ:

> Purchase Limitations
>   Your account must have a successful purchase older than thirty days, but not older than a year in order to access the Marketplace. The purchase of wallet funds, games, DLCs and software meet this requirement. Retail CD key activations and gift purchases do not satisfy this requirement.

And the Spanish version:

> Limitaciones en las compras
>   Para acceder al Mercado de la Comunidad tu cuenta debe tener una compra realizada hace más de treinta días, pero no mayor a un año. La compra de fondos de la Cartera, juegos, DLCs y software te permite cumplir este requisito, pero no la activación de claves de producto o la compra de regalos.

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1047-EDFM-2932&l=english
https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1047-EDFM-2932&l=spanish

Comment: Yes I believe this is the answer OP is looking for, how did you know? Do you know Spanish Studoku?

Comment: @Zerjack No but I understood the English translation

Comment: @Zerjack Enough of it to figure out the question anyway.

Comment: Oh I see, yeah... pretty bad translation if you ask me, but it might have been due a poor choice of words in spanish.

Comment: I assume they mean _received_ gifts do not count, otherwise you could just buy wallet funds (which do count) and use the funds to buy a gift.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how long you have to sell your items once your earn them, the answer is forever - you don't lose the right to sell things unless you become trade-banned for doing something like scamming.

Comment: Well thanks ; but at one point , he had a message , "You need to buy a game / item within the next three months to sell your items" something like that.

Comment: @NegroQueTose If you could post a screen shot of this that would help a great deal in helping to track it down further, but this is the first I have heard of selling limitations on your steam inventory.

Comment: Sorry , but I can not because this happened almost a year ago, in September.

And if I could make the catch, this would be in Spanish , and I think it would be helpful .

This is a question that I have for a while , and no one can help until now.